# Use of Recovery USB Drive On Windows 8.1

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 allows you to create a recovery drive with two options:

1. 256 MB Recovery Drive
2. 3-6 GB Recovery Drive

What's the actual purpose of 256 MB Recovery USB Drive? Can't you already access "System Recovery" from UEFI by pressing F11 on boot if you have got a hidden Recovery Partition on HDD?

Comment: "Can't you already access "System Recovery" from UEFI by pressing F11 on boot?" What do you think happens when you select this option?

Comment: @DavidPostill: You get advanced options [screen](http://support.hp.com/doc-images/463/c03958763.jpg) to repair/restore/troubleshoot windows.

Comment: The recovery drives are used if you want to "refresh" or "reset" your PC.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I already see those options under "Troubleshoot" without 256 MB recovery drive.

Comment: It holds the boot files & Repair tools.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I plugged and booted from the USB recovery drive but the tools look no than different than the ones I saw in F11 "System Recovery" option.

Comment: <shrug> Please read [Create a Recovery Drive or System Repair Disc in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10](https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html).

Comment: "Windows 8/8.1 and 10 allow creating a bootable USB Recovery Drive that goes straight into Recovery Environment (aka Limited Diagnostic Mode), allowing to repair startup, file system and other problems, running System Restore and Refreshing or Resetting your PC (note: Reset this PC in Windows 10 either preserves or removes your personal files and then reinstalls Windows; no desktop programs are kept)."

Comment: "First, make sure you have a blank CD/DVD for System Repair Disc (this option is only available in Windows 8 and 10) or a USB drive with at least 256 MB (megabytes) of total disk space for Windows 8 or 8.1 Recovery Drive."

Comment: A recovery drive is for when you have deleted the recovery partition for whatever reason. For example a hard disk failure and you install a new hard disk.

Comment: Answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the actual purpose of 256 MB Recovery USB Drive?

A recovery drive is used when you have deleted the recovery partition, or the recovery partition cannot be used for some reason.

This might, for example, happen if you have a hard disk failure and you install a new hard disk.

---

#### Create a Recovery Drive or System Repair Disc in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

> Windows 8/8.1 and 10 allow creating a bootable USB Recovery Drive that goes straight into Recovery Environment (aka Limited Diagnostic Mode), allowing to repair startup, file system and other problems, running System Restore and Refreshing or Resetting your PC (note: Reset this PC in Windows 10 either preserves or removes your personal files and then reinstalls Windows; no desktop programs are kept).

...

> First, make sure you have a blank CD/DVD for System Repair Disc (this option is only available in Windows 8 and 10) or a USB drive with at least 256 MB (megabytes) of total disk space for Windows 8 or 8.1 Recovery Drive.

...

Source [Create a Recovery Drive or System Repair Disc in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10](https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html)